# Django Test Case Strings

Tags: django, testing

While testing django the output is a string of ... and xxx and ss. What does that mean?

Comment: There's no test case supplied here, so I am closing this for now. I'm happy to open it again if a case that the answer satisfies is included in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` represents a passed test, while `X` means a failed test.
Then finally when all tests are complete, details of unsuccessfull tests are shown

Comment: and the s there were a few 's' too i am pretty much sure :P .?

Comment: ss's! i never saw any s could you please post a test output?